# How to access current state of component from useEffect without making it a dependency?

Tags: javascript, state, react-hooks, use-effect

I've got the following component (simplified) which, given a note ID, would load and display it. It would load the note in `useEffect` and, when a different note is loaded or when the component gets unmounted, it saves the note.

```
const NoteViewer = (props) => {
    const [note, setNote] = useState({ title: '', hasChanged: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        const note = loadNote(props.noteId);
        setNote(note);

        return () => {
            if (note.hasChanged) saveNote(note); // bug!!
        }
    }, [props.noteId]);

    const onNoteChange = (event) => {
        setNote({ ...note, title: event.target.value, hasChanged: true });
    }

    return (
        <input value={note.title} onChange={onNoteChange}/>
    );
}
```

The issue is that within the `useEffect` I use `note`, which is not part of the dependencies so it means I always get stale data.

However, if I put the note in the dependencies then the loading and saving code will be executed whenever the note is modified, which is not what I need.

So I'm wondering how can I access the current note, without making it a dependency? I've tried to replace the note with a ref, but it means the component no longer updates when the note is changed, and I'd rather not use references.

Any idea what would be the best way to achieve this? Maybe some special React Hooks pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the current state because this component *does not render* on the app render that removes it. Which means your effect never runs that last time.

Using an effect cleanup function is not a good place for this sort of thing. That should really be reserved for cleaning up *that effect* and nothing else.

Instead, whatever logic you have in the app that changes the state to close the `NoteViewer` should also save the note.  So in some parent component (perhaps a `NoteList` or something) you'd save and close like:

```
function NoteList() {
  const [viewingNoteId, setViewingNoteId] = useState(null)

  // other stuff...

  function closeNote() {
    if (note.hasChanged) saveNote(note)
    setViewingNoteId(null)
  }

  return <>{/* ... */}</>
}
```